# How to deep copy a JavaScript object that contains a set

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, set

jQuery deep copy using
`var objCopy = jQuery.extend(true, {}, obj);`

works well for
`var obj = {str: "text", num: 2, arr: [1, 2, 3]}`

but what about for
`var obj = {str: "text", num: 2, set: new Set([1,2,3])}`?

I've found that making changes to `obj.set` **also** changes `objCopy.set`.
Is there a way to drill down to the set inside `obj` and assign a deep copy of that to `objCopy`?

Comment: objects in js are allways transported by reference and not by copy.

Comment: jquery clone function can make copys of dom elements. but i dont know if it works with simple objects too.

Comment: clone() didn't work, and neither did JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));

Comment: what about Object.create() ?

Comment: Cloning a set by itself would work like this: `var set2 = new Set(set1);`.

Comment: What would I pass to Object.create()? I think jQuery.extend picks up the original prototype - at least, it builds a deep copy that contains a set.

Comment: @Xufox - your solution worked for me, but only because in my object I know specifically which key holds a set. By performing the jQuery deep copy and **then** renewing the set into the new copy, I obtained a true deep copy of the original object. I'm still looking for a generalized solution, though. I thought about iterating through the object values with a "typeof" challenge - but pretty much anything but the basics comes back as "object" and I don't want to inadvertently turn everything into a set.

Comment: Try immutable js

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a small `copy` function that will handle it when there is a set.

```
function myCopy(obj) {
  obj = jQueryDeepCopierOfObject(obj); // Deep copy it here

  for (let prop in obj)
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
      if (Set.prototype.isPrototypeOf(obj[prop]))
        obj[prop] = new Set(obj[prop]);

  // hoping there won't be any object in the set.
  return obj;
}
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
var a = { a: "foo",  b: "bar", 
          c: "baz",  set: new Set() };
          
a.set.add("fox");
a.set.add("bat");
a.set.add("wisdom");

var b = mycopy(a);

console.log("a === b: ", a === b); // → false
console.log("a.set === b.set: ",
             a.set === b.set);      // → false

b.set.add("kindness");

console.log("set a has kindness: ",
            a.set.has("kindness")); // → false
console.log("set b has kindness: ",
            b.set.has("kindness")); // → true

function mycopy(obj) {
  obj = Object.assign({}, obj);

  for (let prop in obj)
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
      if (Set.prototype.isPrototypeOf(obj[prop]))
        obj[prop] = new Set(obj[prop]);

  return obj;
}
```